# Leaflet - allow user to draw a Polyline with only two points?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

Leaflet draw allows users to draw lines on a map. There's an example at https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/examples/full.html

I want my users to be able to draw lines consisting of *only* two points. That is, they click, a marker goes down, they move their mouse, click again, and a line is drawn between the two points.

With the default options, the user has to either click the last point again, or the "finish" button.

[image: Screenshot of a map with some lines drawn on it.]

Looking at the documentation for Polyline - http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#polylineoptions - there are several options, but none which specify the maximum number of points a line can have.

Is it possible to set a maximum number of nodes for a line? Or to automatically detect when the second point has been drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using logic with Javascript.

I have written an example quickly bellow on how to do this with comments explaining the resolution process :

```js
// We have the initialisation of the map above

/**
 * We create an object to store the coordinates of the two points
 **/
let coordinates = {
    point1: {
        lat: null,
        lng: null
    },
    point2: {
        lat: null,
        lng: null
    }
}

// Here I created a custom Icon so we can add a custom className to it 
const iconMap = L.icon({
    iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/images/marker-icon.png",

    iconSize:     [25, 41],
    iconAnchor:   [12, 41],
    popupAnchor:  [1, -34],
    className: 'originMarker'
});

let markerOrigin = null;

function onMapClick(e) {
    if (
            coordinates.point1.lat === null && coordinates.point1.lng === null
        &&  coordinates.point2.lat === null && coordinates.point2.lng === null
    ) {
        coordinates.point1.lat = e.latlng.lat;
        coordinates.point1.lng = e.latlng.lng;

        // We add the marker to the map since it is the first point of the line
        markerOrigin = L.marker(
            [ e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng ],
            { icon: iconMap }
        ).addTo(map);
    } else if (
        coordinates.point1.lat !== null
        && coordinates.point1.lng !== null
        && coordinates.point2.lat === null
        && coordinates.point2.lng === null
    ) {
        coordinates.point2.lat = e.latlng.lat;
        coordinates.point2.lng = e.latlng.lng;
        
        // We have enough points (2) to create a line
        const line = [
            [ coordinates.point1.lat, coordinates.point1.lng ],
            [ coordinates.point2.lat, coordinates.point2.lng ]
        ];

        L.polyline(line, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
        
        // we remove the marker
        document.getElementsByClassName('originMarker')[0].remove();
    } else {
        coordinates.point1.lat = e.latlng.lat;
        coordinates.point1.lng = e.latlng.lng;

        coordinates.point2.lat = null;
        coordinates.point2.lng = null;

        markerOrigin = L.marker(
            [ e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng ],
            { icon: iconMap }
        ).addTo(map);
    }

    console.log(coordinates);
}

// we bind a function to the map to detect the click event
map.on('click', onMapClick);
```